# Laravel Deployment all routes works except / show 404

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, deployment, http-status-code-404, ionos

I am currently trying to deploy my Laravel 10 site to Ionos .
I already changed the .htaccess but I have a now a problem, every routes works perfectly fine except the index one .
For example mysite.com/contact, or mysite.com/login displays properly my views, but mysite.com returns a 404 error.

My htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    
    

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    
    # Force https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTM_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Force no www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have laravel debugbar installed, I can show you what it returns me :[Laravel debugbar error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXynN.png)

I think it has something to do with the fact that it is try to get to mysite.com/public/public
why it tries two times to access to public folder ?

What do you guys it would come from?
If you need more details just tell me.
And thank you for your patience

Comment: You mention a "public" folder? Where is this "public" folder?

Comment: Can you show your directory structure where laravel is placed?

Comment: You mentioned that the URL `mysite.com` returns a 404 error. Check if accessing `mysite.com/index.php` directly works. If it does, then the problem is likely with the mod_rewrite rules. If you're using Apache as your web server, ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled. You can enable it by running: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` After enabling it, restart Apache.

Comment: mode rewrite is enabled in your server or not?

Comment: cengsemihsahin You're right, I can access through mysite/index.php. But I don't know where to add this command to, I use Ionos, and when I try to execute commands from SSH it says : " -bash: sudo: command not found " Do you have any idea on how to put this command ??

Comment: My public folder is located at /sites/mysite.com/public, note that on Ionos my "/site/ "folder is inside a "/" folder

Comment: Can you check if `/sites/app.mysite.com/public` also has a `.htaccess` in it?

Comment: It does that is where the htaccess you see in my first comment is located